# how to use this.children on ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

hi guys i have problem in ajax that i used a for each loop on php page that produce table rows with some buttons problem is the post method only return the id and other attr of first row how can i get the other rows attribute
here is the codes

```
$('.erja').click(function() {
  $('.load_erja').show();
  $('.load_erja').css({
    "background-color": "blue",
    "color": "white"
  });
  $('.load_erja').html("process");
  var id = $(".new_id").val();
  var kar = $(".kar").val();
  var reggg_sub = 'reggg_sub';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'check.php',
    data: {
      'id': id,
      'kar': kar,
      'reggg_sub': reggg_sub
    },
    success: function(html) {
      eror(parseInt(html));
    }
  })
});
```

and here is the html code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit_<?php echo $rows['id']?>" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="#edit_<?php echo $rows['id']?>" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-me ">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div dir="rtl" class="modal-body">
        <form action="">
          <div class="from-group">
            <input class="new_id" id="new_id_<?php echo $rows['id']?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $rows['id']?>">
            <select class="form-control kar" name="e" id="kar_<?php echo $rows['id']?>">
              <option value="-1">test1</option>
              <option value="1">test</option>
            </select>
            <a href="#" id="load_erja_<?php echo $rows['id']?>" type="button" class="btn btnnormal text-center load form-control load_erja "></a>
            <a href="#" id="erja_<?php echo $rows['id']?>" type="button" class="btn btn-success btnnormal text-center submit form-control  erja">ارجاع</a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="close" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> بستن</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<?php } ?>
</table>
```

i want to use this method on ajax but it wont get any value
$( this ).children( 'input' ).attr("id");

Comment: If you are not getting enough data from your ajax call, you need to show us your check.php

Comment: @FailedUnitTest ty for answer but i get all data problem is i want to send all table rows data not just first one but i get only the first one data on post method

Comment: You mean, you want to send more data 'to' check.php?

Comment: @FailedUnitTest for example i want to get second row info like id but $(.new_ad).val post me the first ones id and info

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently: 
Create a function like this:

```
function CheckKar(idParam, karParam){
 $('.load_erja').show();
  $('.load_erja').css({
    "background-color": "blue",
    "color": "white"
  });
  $('.load_erja').html("process");
  var id = $(".new_id").val();
  var kar = $(".kar").val();
  var reggg_sub = 'reggg_sub';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'check.php',
    data: {
      'id': idParam,
      'kar': karParam,
      'reggg_sub': reggg_sub
    },
    success: function(html) {
      console.log(html);
    }
  });
}
```

then create these kind of links in php: `<a href='http://www.google.com' onclick='return CheckKar(0,"mercedes")' class='erja'>check</a>`